# How to draw Sprite with touch points in LibGDX

Tags: android, libgdx, sprite

I want to draw some path with user's touch. if users moves finger from one position to another position a path will be drawn exactly as user moved finger.

We can draw a line with by defining color but i want to draw that line with sprite(image).

What I exactly meant is I just want to use image using sprite instead of using color to draw line. is it possible with LibGDX? if yes , how can we do that? and how will I generate image to use as sprite for that?

Comment: Yes, it's possible to do anything. You need to be more specific about exactly what you want, what you've tried, and why it's not working.